# Flutter: How to listen to streamSubscription in batches

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am trying to create a post system with **geo location filter**. I want to fetch all the **results in the given radius** and then **paginate** it to reduce the reads and to be developer-cost efficient.

In the codes below, ***I have achieved half of the goal.*** I am retrieving the first 10 documents from the documents list that are found within the radius.

And it's working properly, but the **load more function isn't quite working.**

Because I used `streamSubscription` to listen and then to `pause the subscription` while the user is **going through the results already retrieved**, and only `resume the subscription` when user calls for **more results** and then `pause the subscription` again to avoid any abrupt updates to the results in realtime.

I've gone through many ways to achieve it, but since I'm not so great, I haven't been able to accomplish it. I found that we could achieve the desired results with `streamController`, but **I don't know how to use it** and also I'm not sure if it would keep the **reads minimal like subScription or not.**

Please help, for my **whole application depends** on this little guy.

Thanks in advance.

```
class geoFlutterFirePaginatedSystem extends StatefulWidget {
  const geoFlutterFirePaginatedSystem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<geoFlutterFirePaginatedSystem> createState() => _geoFlutterFirePaginatedSystemState();
}

class _geoFlutterFirePaginatedSystemState extends State<geoFlutterFirePaginatedSystem> {

  // ----------- Variables --------------- //
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final geo = Geoflutterfire();

  GeoFirePoint myLocation = GeoFirePoint(13.7738153, 100.5667812);

  late Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream;
  StreamSubscription<List<DocumentSnapshot>>? streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: _firestore.collection('Listings')).within(
      center: myLocation,
      radius: 1,
      field: 'location', // Replace with your geolocation field name
      strictMode: true,
    );

    getResults(false);
    super.initState();
  }

  // ----------- Variables --------------- //
  var resultList = [];
  bool hasData = true;

  getResults(bool moreData) async {
    // Listen to the stream and handle sorting and pagination.
    streamSubscription = stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) async {
      if(documentList.isEmpty) return;

      if(!moreData) {
        var dataBatch = [];
        // For the initial fetch, retrive 10 results
        dataBatch.addAll(documentList.take(10).map((doc) {
          var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return data['query'].toString();
        }));

        // ------- Adding delay to add the await operation to get all function called in order written ------ //
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1));

        // ----- Pausing Stream to stop realtime updates ---- ///
        streamSubscription?.pause();

        // -------- Adding data to real List from Temp List ----------- //
        resultList.addAll(dataBatch);

        // -------- If the data is less than batch size, it mean there's no more data available...setting hasData false ----------- //
        if(dataBatch.length < 10) {
          hasData = false;
          streamSubscription?.cancel();
        }

      } else {
        // on User's demand, retrive next 10 results
        var dataBatch = [];
        dataBatch.addAll(documentList.skip(resultList.length).take(10).map((doc) {
          var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return data['query'].toString();
        }));

        // ------- Adding delay to add the await operation to get all function called in order written ------ //
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1));

        // ----- Pausing Stream to stop realtime updates ---- ///
        streamSubscription?.pause();

        // -------- Adding data to real List from Temp List ----------- //
        resultList.addAll(dataBatch);

        // -------- If the data is less than batch size, it mean there's no more data available...setting hasData false ----------- //
        if(dataBatch.length < 10) {
          hasData = false;
          streamSubscription?.cancel();
        }
      }

      // Pausing the stream so that data wouldn't update abruptly while user's viewing a result
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  moreListing() async {
    // Resuming the stream to get the data from the stream again
    streamSubscription?.resume();
    await getResults(true);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    streamSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          if(hasData) ... [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                print("Clicked");
                await moreListing();
              },
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 40,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text("More Data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
              ),
            ),
          ] else ... [
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 40,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("No more Data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
            ),
          ]
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text("Results (${resultList.length})", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black,),),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: resultList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Text("${resultList[index]}"),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to need paginated requests, where you ask for items 10 at a time in separate Streams, and use a cursor to get "the next batch".

Comment: can you elaborate, maybe, please! @RandalSchwartz

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the `sink` operation with the stream controller:

`streamController.sink(list)`